# Safari slows network speed when opening multiple tabs

Tags: browser, safari

When I open multiple tabs in Safari using Ctrl+Click and rapidly slows my network speed. Sometimes it is so slow that it does not open those pages and any other page (It says "Looking for www..." in other browsers too).

Has anybody observed this? is this happening to any of you?

Comment: In other words is there a way to check the number of connections/threads opened by Safari and their statuses?

Comment: How fast is your internet connection, and what page does it load when you open a new tab? Is it a large page?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because each time you load a tab, the browser tries to download that page from the Internet? And the more things you're trying to download simultaneously, the more it will consume available bandwidth, thus slowing down your network speed.

Or, in other words, it's because "you're clogging up the tubes"!

So, yeah, I've noticed this. But it's not a problem with Safari.

Comment: It is not about the usual utilization of the bandwidth. It just happens with Safari, when I open multiple tabs quickly. But when I open the same number of tabs in Firefox all pages loads quickly and no other Internet tool is affected. But when I open the same tabs simultaneously in Safari it clogs and all Internet tools become slow.